# English numbers are shown Persian in asp website

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, font-face, multilingual, persian

Hi I have a multi language website (English and Persian). I used font face for display different fonts for different languages. If I add a persian font to my font face all numbers including English numbers in english pages shown as persian numbers and if I just use english font-face all numbers are shown in english.
What should I do?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'myNazanin';
    src: 
    local('B Nazanin'),
    url('../fonts/BNazanin.eot') format('eot'),  /* IE6–8 */
    url('../fonts/BNazanin.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, 
    Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/BNazanin.ttf') format('truetype');
 }
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'my New Roman';
     src: 
    local('Times New Roman'),

 }
 body{

   font-family:myNazanin,'my New Roman';
 }
```

Comment: If you mean you want to display numbers like 123 in Times rather than BNazanin, you will need the [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) descriptor. Or if that doesn't work for you, make use of the [`:lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) pseudo-class. Or maybe something else. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The user can choose English or Persian Language from the navbar language icon. I used .resx (asp.net globalization) files to substitute the text for these languages in each page. when the user change the language to persian or english the text substitute successfully and the Persian/english font works on the text but the problem is when the language is english if there is any number between the text it shows in persian like : " This company is founded on 2012" (2012 will be shown by persian numbers.
I used :lang too, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved! My Persian font wasn't standard font for web! I changed it to an standard font and now everything is working just fine!